# How to stop a running shell script if it executes some dangerous operations?

Tags: scripting, shell

I mean, how to dynamically stop a running shell script based on what operation it's doing. Because some dangerous commands such as `rm`, if using regex before running, some edge situations may escape, like

```sh
#!/bin/bash
name=""
$name rm a.py
```

will still remove `a.py`.

So is there a way to detect what the next command is of a running script and stop it if matches.

Maybe complex regex can do this before running, but I want to know if there is a nice solution with running scripts.

### More

I am not allowed to modify the scripts because it was given by others.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't run untrusted third-party scripts in the first place.

Filtering shell calls *might* be achieved when they lead to forking other binaries using AppArmor, SELinux, GrSec or other security policing tools.

However pure bash can do way too much without forking for it to be enough.

Don't run the script or read it before you run it. If you don't trust the third-party provider but **must** run it, you're left with reading it.